# App Icons Missing in Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-center, icons

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04.

In the software center, [uninstalled apps are missing their icons.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inT9E.png)

Apps that are installed [mostly have their icons.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODaVT.png)

I also downloaded Gnome Software center and it has a similar problem. in Gnome Software, it is only the apps on the front page (editor's pick, recommended) [that are missing icons.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKRu1.png) The rest of the apps seem to have their icons [when I select a category.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sc7H6.png)

Curiously under installed apps, Discord's icon appears in gnome software center, but not in ubuntu software center (I installed it through ubuntu software center).

Also, as seen from the screenshots, my sidebar icons are fine.

How do I fix the icons in the software center? Preferably without a reinstall.

Comment: They take awhile to show up...it's weird.

Comment: perhaps I should add that they worked fine on my previous install of ubuntu 20.04. After reinstalling yesterday, the icons no longer properly load. It doesn't seem to be a matter of taking time to show up, they simply do not. one minute, ten, more; doesn't matter. If I had to take a layman's guess, it is as if the program is unable to find the proper icons.

Comment: I started off with 20.04 and it took a day to finally show up, but that has elapsed so if it is still an issue then we have a problem.

Comment: What icon set did you install? Not sure if that matters....mine is Yaru-Dark. (Gnome Tweaks)